# Year Missing in Bibliography Entries - elsarticle

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle

The document does not include the year on some references even though year is clearly in the .bib file. For the example below, the saidur year is output, but the laakso year is not. I cannot figure out what's causing the discrepancy. I tried changing bibliography style from elsarticle-num to other options from [here](http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Model-wise_bibliographic_style_files), but always get the same result. No year.

.tex file sample:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,review,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
...
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{bib}
```

.bib file (bib.bib) sample:

```
@article{saidur,
  title={A review on global wind energy policy},
  author={Saidur, R and Islam, MR and Rahim, NA and Solangi, KH},
  journal={Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
  volume={14},
  number={7},
  pages={1744--1762},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{laakso,
  title={State-of-the-art of wind energy in cold climates},
  author={Laakso, Timo and Holttinen, H and Ronsten, G and Tallhaug, L and Horbaty, R and Baring-Gould, I and Lacroix, A and Peltola, E and Tammelin, B},
  journal={IEA annex XIX},
  volume={24},
  year={2003}
}
```

Comment: It seems like a bug in the bibliography style file, because if I add a mock `pages` field to the second entry, the year appears.